# Bind Multiple Events in Single .on() Call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright have been working to switch to jQuery 1.7's new and improved [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function instead of relying on .live().

Here's what get's me, when you've got multiple bindings, .live() was great letting you do them all in a simple function. For example:

```
$('.my_thing').live({
   mouseover: function(e) {
     console.log('hey imma moused over');   
   },
   mouseout: function(e) {
     console.log('hey imma moused out');   
   }
 });
```

Very simple! How would you do this with .on()? Here's as close as I can get and it still feels messy.

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.my_thing', function(e) {
     console.log('hey imma moused over');   
  }).on('mouseout','.my_thing', function(e) {
     console.log('hey imma moused out');   
 });
```

Feels messy, no? There must be a better way.

**PS** - This has got to be one of the worst functions *EVER* if you're trying to learn more about it on Google.

Comment: Kind of ironic that you are linking to the docs where the answer can be found at the top :P

Comment: Is that what .on( events-map [, selector] [, data] ) is saying? I sometimes just go cross-eyed looking at these things without examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an events map in addition to a selector:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseover: function(e) {
        console.log('hey imma moused over');   
    },
    mouseout: function(e) {
        console.log('hey imma moused out');   
    }
}, '.my_thing');
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/zJtWR/)

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).on({
   mouseover: function(e) {
     console.log('hey imma moused over');   
   },
   mouseout: function(e) {
     console.log('hey imma moused out');   
   }
 }, '.my_thing' );
```